# What's the point of initialising an unnamed C++ parameter?

Tags: c++, parameters, initialization

What's the point of initialising an unnamed C++ parameter? For example:

```
void foo(int = 0) {}
```

Comment: There's no value to doing this, except in waging a silly bet about if it will or will not compile (assuming most people would refuse to believe that such a useless construct will compile).

Comment: There is really no point in this. Where have you seen it? I am quite surprised if the compiler does not warn.

Comment: I've now seen a good example of this when using `std::enable_if` with a function argument. From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if): `template <class T> T foo2(T t, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value >::type* = 0) { return t; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can imagine in the context of callback functions the construct might be useful:

```
#include <iostream>

// Please assume the callback is an external library:
typedef void (*callback_function)(int);
callback_function callback;

void foo(int = 0) {
    std::cout << "Hello\n";
}

int main() {
    callback = foo;
    callback(1);
    foo();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But why would I not have: `typedef void (*callback_function0)(); callback_function0 callback0; void foo0() { std::cout << "Hello\n"; }` ?

Comment: @user2023370 Assume the callback is an external library

Answer (score 2):

A declaration has no need of a parameter name. The definition does, however. Also, the default parameter cannot be repeated in the definition. Here's a small program that works (but I don't know why you would want to do something like this, really...):

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int = 5);

int main() {
    foo();
    foo(3);

    return 0;
}

void foo(int i) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

The output is

```
5
3
```

Answer (score 1):

It will serve as the default parameter value. It belongs in the function declaration.

Comment: The default value is useless if code cannot find the value (since there's no name to access it with), and unfortunately the line of code in the question _does_ compile.

Comment: @Tyler: Since when are unnamed parameters in definitions forbidden? I often use them to avoid *unused variable*-warnings.